# convert varchar to date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a column where date is stored as Sep-19,Nov-13,Aug-19 which is in varchar type i have to convert it to date type

Comment: Look into using `STR_TO_DATE`.  Have you spent any time researching this problem?

Comment: yes ,I need accurate answer for it

Comment: It is best to cleanse the data as you store it, not as you fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2011-09-28 18:01:00', 120) -- to convert it to Datetime

SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(30), @date ,105) -- italian format [28-09-2011 18:01:00]
+ ' ' + SELECT CONVERT( VARCHAR(30), @date ,108 ) -- full date [with time/minutes/sec]
```